# VSTS Scrum Across Multiple Projects

Tags: azure-devops

Is there the possibility of being able to build out a Dashboard with burndown in VSTS across multiple projects. This dashboard would not contain a repo, tasks or any other item it would only be used to consolidate multiple projects tasks into one central location for the purpose of a scrum. Thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Burndown** widget for different project, but can’t select multiple projects in a Burndown widget.

[Configure a Burndown or Burnup widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets)

On the other hand, there is the sample to build custom widget extension that may benefit you:

[Build a dashboard widget extension that calls the Analytics Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/extend-analytics/widget-extensions-against-analytics-service)